# Tanker exhaust sequence blows sulfuric acid everywhere and I need to rig up something to slow the exhaust without impeding flow rate

Tags: chemical-engineering

I am not an engineer myself and I'm hoping you guys can help me with a project I am working on.

So we receive rail car tankers full of sulfuric acid that we pressurize like a beer keg to offload the chemical into tanks. The issue is that once the truck is empty we have to depressurize it through the same 0.75 inch PFA line we pressurize through and it shoots 96% sulfuric acid up into the exhaust which then rains down into the cabinet and escapes through seams and is damaging the surrounding infrastructure.

The way the system is designed I can't just tap the 0.75 inch exhaust straight into the cheap cpvc drain plumbing because its junk and it will probably cause another leak and well, the engineering team just won't let me. I do have a degree in chemistry and a minor in math so I'm familiar with some basic fluid dynamics so I started going over silencer and exhaust muffler designs to try and cobble together something that can deposit the sulfuric into a built in drain cup that has its own sump to remove it safely. The problem is that I have to build this thing out of stuff I can hunt down in the wild on my own. Thus far that's meant cobbling together PFA fittings in an attempt to open the exhaust into an apparatus that increases the volume of the exhaust pipe. This quickly became unfeasible as I stacked T fittings to direct the exhaust into a bundle of workable half inch lines. Just increasing the exhaust line volume to 2 inches requires 4 T fittings and the design quickly becomes to large and unwieldy without slowing the exhaust speed sufficiently to keep it from flinging sulfuric everywhere. I can't reduce the line size or impede the overall flow rate because it will slow the depressurization sequence.

I was curious if you fine people could clue me in on finer design points or principles I'm missing. I would love to just size the line up to four inches and perforate the end like a muzzle break on a rifle but unfortunately the largest single line size I have access too is 1 and 1/4 inch and the line itself is difficult to work with once it gets over a half inch plus reducers to size it to that point are nigh impossible to find.

Comment: I am aware I confused the line diameter with volume. I apologize for the typo.

Comment: don't comment on it ... use the edit button and fix it

Comment: why did you use the `chemical-engineering` tag?

Comment: The car must be *depressurized* prior to unloading. Use pumps on the transfer line to pump the liquid out of the car. Never pressurize a hazmat car during unloading. Unloading lines must be in accordance with rail standards and have anti backsiphon valves on the hard pipe and leakproof fittings on the car adapter and valves on the flex line. The rail carrier should be able to assist you with transfer equipment.